# Amazon s3 images // Image from url download right away

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Quite an S3 newb', I wonder why my images stored on s3 via cloudfront downloads directly when called from its url in the browser's address bar. It does not display in the browser, as any images would do

**— update following the first answer —**

Doing a simple `curl -s -I {url}`, there are no content-types in the headers :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 39128
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Wed, 10 Sep 2014 16:57:52 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 27 Aug 2014 14:56:01 GMT
ETag: "aef5ede65bedeb0c9052edaf5a97b9e4"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Server: AmazonS3
Age: 53
X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 28e1bd291bf9b996c8d272e4eb691366.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id: xIB30ZnQJpZDS7d8cnsbDUNloQowwIsu-B71axGeh1H5mKM1eZZi2w==
```

Going in the s3 console, the content-type of the image appears in the metadata part if I check the properties of the files

Feedback appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the content type for the files you upload. For instance, a jpeg should have content type image/jpeg. You can do this by using the AWS console for S3.

Here's a list of content types: http://s3browser.com/features-content-mime-types-editor.php

Comment: arf problem is the content type is set correctly (I'm using ruby was-sdk and it does that automatically, been on the amazon console, checked it, that what I can see in the metadata part of any files). could it be cloud front related ? On top of that, this "download" thing does not happened on every browser